# Jest passing an object to expect().toBeCalledWith()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using jest to test my react components and I'm using `expect(...).toBeCalledWith(...);` to test if a function has been called with specific parameters, and it works fine with value types.

The problem is I want to test a function that takes object as a parameter so when you call `expect(myFunc).toBeCalledWith(object);` the test always fails because of course the two object compared to each other do not have the same reference.

so how can I solve this problem ?

a sample code of what I'm trying to test is

```
it('the function should be called with the correct object', () => {
    api.submitForm = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve());
    const wrapper = shallow(<component />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    instance.submitForm();
    const object = {
      foo : 'foo',
      bar: 'bar'
    };
    // this always fails even the function is called with the same object values
    expect(api.submitForm).toBeCalledWith(object);
  });
```

An error message would be something like this

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
      [{"bar": "bar", "foo": "foo"}]
    But it was called with:
      [{"bar": "bar", "foo": "foo"}]
```

### **Update**

it seems the below code works fine

```
  expect(api.submitForm).toBeCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
     foo : 'foo',
      bar: 'bar'
    }),
  );
```

however, if the object contains a property with array value, the above solution doesn't work

```
const obj = {
  foo : ['foo1', 'foo2'],
  bar: 'bar'
}
```

Comment: The problem could be something else. I have used the above pattern in my code and it works as expected

Comment: Mention the jest version please...

Comment: The jest doc itself at here shows that they are comparing the value, not the reference,
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-

Comment: I'm using jest `20.0.4`, and the problem happens if you have an array property in your object

Comment: the second solution works now I've discovered a typo in my code.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Looking at the jest doc (https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject). It seems you can do something like this:

```
 expect(api.submitForm).toBeCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
     foo : 'foo',
      bar: 'bar'
    }),
  );
```

Comment: This would work. But the real intention of expect.objectContaining is slightly different

Comment: this works fine actually, but the problem if your object contains an array property

Comment: Man I love good documentation! Thanks [jest] team!

Comment: This doesn't work if being expected object contains a object in itself, and we need to match on this nested object property. What can be done in this case? Ex {headers:{a:10},z:20} need to match on "a" equals 10

Answer (score 9):

you can use `.mock.calls[callIdx][paramIdx]`
description + example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939921/2519073

in your case

```
expect(api.submitForm.mock.calls[0][0]).toMatchObject( // use whatever matcher you want
    {
      foo : ['foo1', 'foo2'],
      bar: 'bar'
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you your function is called with arguments

```
function update( userId, partialUserObject ){
   // update logic
}
```

You can use

```
expect(update).toBeCalledWith('mockUserId',
   expect.objectContaining({
     username:'hello-world',
     displayName: 'Hello World'
   })
);
```

- array: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectarraycontainingarray
- object: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject