# Using Jest, how to check arguments passed in a mocked function

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest for mock and spy a node_modules library, but I need support:

this is the code to test

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')

const mg = mailgun({
  apiKey: process.env.MAIL_GUN_API_KEY,
  domain: process.env.MAIL_GUN_DOMAIN,
  host: process.env.MAIL_GUN_HOST
})

module.exports = (data) => mg.messages().send(data)
```

now testing it

```sh
__mock__/mailgun-js.js
```

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')
jest.genMockFromModule('mailgun-js')
module.exports = mailgun
```

```sh
tests/test.js
```

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')

jest.mock('mailgun-js', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => ({
    messages: () => ({
      send: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
    })
  }))
})

expect(mailgun).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
expect(mailgun).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  apiKey: process.env.MAIL_GUN_API_KEY,
  domain: process.env.MAIL_GUN_DOMAIN,
  host: process.env.MAIL_GUN_HOST
})
```

Right now toHaveBeenCalledTimes and toHaveBeenCalledWith works, but I would also check the argument passed to .send (data)

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939921/863110?

Comment: in this way I can check only arguments passed directly to mailgun (apikey, domain and host), but not the one passed to send()

Comment: You're right. I added an answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can spy on the `send` function in your mock then verify that `itHaveBeenCalled` when you run `add(data)`

Like this:

```js
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')
const mockSend = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());

jest.mock('mailgun-js', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => ({
    messages: () => ({
      send: mockSend
    })
  }))
})

test('test', () => {
  const add = require('./add');
  expect(mailgun).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  expect(mailgun).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    apiKey: process.env.MAIL_GUN_API_KEY,
    domain: process.env.MAIL_GUN_DOMAIN,
    host: process.env.MAIL_GUN_HOST
  });

  const data = {foo: 'bar'};
  add(data);
  expect(mockSend).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data);
});
```

Pay attention - if you'll change the `mockSend` name to a name without prefix `mock`, you'll get an error:

> The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.

Comment: ohh it works!!! thank you. I've just tried a similar solution, but without prefix `mock` and I got out-of-scope error.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that :)

Comment: What is this line `require('./add')` ? Is this something provided by `jest` ?

Comment: @malat it's the module the OP wants to test.